Ambiguity in Limits of Integration
If in a definite integral, the variable in the differential is a function of an independent variable like $x$, are the limits of integration for $x$ or for the function ?.
Example:
Consider
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}{\rm d}\sin\left(x\right)
$$
Are the limits $0$ and $\pi/2$ for $x$ or for $\sin\left(x\right)$ ?.

It should be for $\sin x$. You could write the lower limit of integration as $x=0$ instead of just $0$.

No, it should be for $x$. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral

or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration.

I agree, for $x$.  More generally, see the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f(x) ,dg(x)$.

I asked my teacher, he said that the limits are for sin $x$.
